# Handling multiple raster files and executing unit conversions on them: R

Tags: r, raster

I've dug around a lot for an answer to this and wasn't able to find anything, so here I am.

I have a whole bunch of ascii raster files corresponding to air temperature and dew point temperature of a certain area over 744 hourly time steps.  (So I have 744 air temp and 744 dew point files corresponding to a 31-day month).  The files are only about 45 kB each.

I want to stack them together so I can perform some analyses on them, and I also want to convert their units from K to deg F.

The file names air Tair1.txt, Tair2.txt, ... Tair744.txt  and Eair1.txt, Eair2.txt, ... Eair744.txt.

Using the raster package, I can easily load all the files as rasters:

```
for (i in 1:744) {
assign(paste0("Tair",i),raster(paste0("Tair",i,".txt")))
assign(paste0("Eair",i),raster(paste0("Tair",i,".txt")))
}
```

I've tried to use ls() with pattern or glob2rx to define just the raster file names and
then do conversions on them, or to do something similar to join them in a stack, but to no avail. I also tried mget, values(mget(filename)) and things like that to get at the values in a loop.

I know R doesn't handle large datasets very well, but I'm thinking these aren't really that large so there should be something pretty simple?

I would appreciate any help and advice!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The raster package's `RasterStack` is for this:

```
library(raster)
files <- paste0("Tair",1:744,".txt")
rs <- stack(files)
```

Why do you have these files in text format though? Who imposed this disaster on you? I suspect your individual layers have insufficient metadata, so try one and see if it's sensible. You can use `extent(rs) <-` and `projection(rs) <-` to fix:

```
r <- raster(files[1])
print(r)
```

Don't use `assign()` that's just creating a mess.